# SIGABRT error when pushing segue from one UIViewController to another

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making a simple app in which I've linked one `UIViewController` to another through button using `Push segue`, but when the button is tapped it gives `SIGABRT error`, I can't figure out why ?

I've also checked for any other segues related to this button which I must have deleted by mistake, but no there is no other triggered segue.

This is my `UIViewController` code and I have this simple circular animation.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!

    let transition = CircularTransition()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButton.frame.size.width / 2

    }


    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }



    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.transitionMode = .present
        transition.startingPoint = menuButton.center
        transition.circleColor = menuButton.backgroundColor!

        return transition
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.transitionMode = .dismiss
        transition.startingPoint = menuButton.center
        transition.circleColor = menuButton.backgroundColor!

        return transition
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Comment: Look in your console output for error information. You'll likely see something like this: `"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:"`

Comment: yes, I do "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)"

Comment: Is there other error information? Is this happening on a specific code line? Can yo used a breakpoint and step through to see when it happens?

Comment: it also says "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "Reminder" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView."

Comment: OK - so you are trying to load a UITableViewController - either through code or via segue - with the identifier "Reminder"... but it looks like your view controller with identifier "Reminder" in your storyboard does not have a UITableView... look for that in your storyboard.

Comment: I have a UITableView in my storyboard with identifier "Reminder" and also I have a prototype cell.

Comment: Look closer... the error says "Reminder" table view *controller* was instantiated, but does not have an associated UITableView. Something in your storyboard is not "connected" correctly. Maybe try creating a new "Reminder" table view controller.

Comment: yes that worked, I created a new one and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding table or deleagtes through storyboard check image for broken connections....

[image]